Auto update image in Photoshop
Creating Jersey Mockup. Im using Coreldraw & Photoshop. Created Illustrator in Coreldraw and exported as jpg. In the mockup im using the image, Every time i do some adjustment i have to export and drag the image and save. Then it updates. Is there any way if i export the image automatically update in photoshop (like illustrator and After effect we do so, when do some illustrator and save the file, After Effect automatically updates). So any way to just export the file from coreldraw it should update in photoshop layer. Reason i can see live view. Any suggestion or help. Thanks.



You seem to be talking about the functionality of a Smart Object in Photoshop.  Basically it's an external file, which if you overwrite should update in Photoshop.  Have a look here on the Adobe site where this functionality is explained.

If you're exporting as a jpg.. then using that jpg.. then no, there's not dynamic ability.. because you are exporting. I'd try just placing the CorelDraw file. (I don't know if Photoshop supports Corel file placement). Worse case, use Illustrator rather than Corel, save file as .ai then place that in Photoshop. Essentially "exporting" is your entire issue.
